# Reading CSV files with different schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have two `csv` files on S3:

```
# a1.csv
a,b
3,4
```

and

```
# b2.csv
a,c
1,"text"
```

I would like to read both of them at once, making sure the final dataframe consists of all columns across all files, like this:

```
+---+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+
|  1|null|text|
|  3|   4|null|
+---+----+----+
```

I tried both `inferSchema` and `schema` options but they do not provide the result i would expect.

Option 1:

```
df = spark.read\
    .option("header", True)\
    .option("inferSchema", True)\
    .csv("s3a://test/*.csv")\
    .show()

+---+----+
|  a|   c|
+---+----+
|  1|text|
|  3|   4|
+---+----+
```

Option 2:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

schema = StructType([
StructField("a", IntegerType(), False)
,StructField("b", IntegerType(), True)
,StructField("c", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read\
    .option("header", True)\
    .schema(schema)\
    .csv("s3a://test/*.csv")\
    .show()

+---+----+----+
|  a|   b|   c|
+---+----+----+
|  1|null|null|
|  3|   4|null|
+---+----+----+
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If the file format is parquet then we can merge schema easily using **mergeSchema** option by pointing to folder which contains multiple files but for CSV file we don't have that option.

You can use **unionByName** function to get the desired result.

Iterate over the folder and read file into dataframe then you can call **unionByName** function.

```
df1.unionByName(df2, True)
```